# How would I mock this $resource service in my controller in jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm new to testing and trying to get this Jasmine test setup with my controller in AngularJS.  I have a  reusable service I would like to mock, but I keep getting errors (specifically, the service always fails and I get "Cannot connect to the API service").  Below is what I have tried.

My Controller:

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .controller('myController', myController);

function myController($scope, apiService) {
  apiService.url = "/api/getAccount";
  apiService.call().get({ accountNumber: 123 }).$promise.then(function (data) {
      $scope.account = data;
  }, function () {
    throw new Error("Cannot connect to the API service");
  });
```

The Service:

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .factory('apiService', apiService);

function apiService($resource) {
    return {
        url: '/api/..',
        call: function () {
            return $resource(this.url);
        }
    }
};
```

My Jasmine Test:

```
describe('myController', function () {
     var $q,
     $rootScope,
     $scope,
     mockAccountListResponse = { Account: [{ //stuff }] },
     mockApiService,
     deferred;

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function (_$q_, _$rootScope_) {
    $q = _$q_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
  }));

  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();

  mockApiService = {
     call: function () {
       return {
         get: function () {
           deferred = $q.defer();
           deferred.reject("Error Connecting to API Service");
           return { $promise: deferred.promise };
         }
       }
     }
   }

    spyOn(mockApiService, 'call').and.callThrough();

    $controller('dashboardController', {
      '$scope': $scope,
      'apiService': mockApiService,
    });
  }));

  describe('Upon calling the ApiService', function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
      deferred.resolve(mockAccountResponse);
      $rootScope.$apply();
    });

    it('should get the account successfully', function () {
      expect(mockApiService.call).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are actually causing the problem to happen when you set up your mocks.  Do you see the line where you say:

`deferred.reject("Error Connecting to API Service");`

You are basically saying, whenever this mock service is called, return a rejected promise so that anyone else that uses it will get this rejected value and no `.then`'s will ever be entered.  Now, you're just checking to see if `.get` was called, but I think it's throwing the unhandled exception from the promise before your assertion is considered.  Why don't you just resolve instead?  `deferred.resolve("Here's a good test value");`

Since you are new to testing, I'd be remiss if I didn't mention that there is a cool mock library released with angular itself that automatically mocks anything that uses the underlying $httpBackend service for you - and that includes the angular $resource service as it relies on $httpBackend.

If you setup a test html page that includes said library, all of your network requests will be mocked and you will have access to the values they tried to send over the wire.

This is the mock library: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.  I recommend giving it a try!

Comment: Replacing deferred.reject with deferred.resolve (which I had down below) fixed the issue and the test succeeds now,  thank you!  Also that is very helpful advice about ngMock, as I thought $httpBackend applied only to $http calls, not $resource.  I will definitely look into that.